# Hiding quiz button with javascript and not accepting empty answer with ENTER

Tags: javascript, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have a form divided into 5 parts, like a questionnaire. At the end of each question, there is a button to go to the next one, however, I need the button to only appear if the user types at least 1 number in the input field.

The code must comply with what is specified below:

1. It is not allowed to type characters that are not between 0 and 9.
2. If the user does not type anything, and presses ENTER, it cannot skip to the next question.
3. If the user enters the number, for example, 50, and erases the 50, the button should disappear again.
4. If the user doesn't write any number, and chooses a pre-filled number (which was in the browser's cache), the button has to appear.

I tried two different codes.

The first comply 3) and 4), but no 1) and 2):

```
<input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" onkeyup="check()" />

<div class="text-end mt-3">
  <input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function check() {
    var count = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');
    if (count.value.length < 2) {
      document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

The second comply 1) and 2), but not 3) and 4):

```
<input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event)" maxlength="2" />

<div class="text-center mt-3">
    <input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function justNumbers(evt2) {
        var age = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');

        var key = evt2.keyCode;

        if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {

            if (age.value.length < 0) {
                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried to run similar routine as above with `onkeyup` to fulfill 1) but it didn't work. I tried to use `onchange`, but it didn't work either.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `<form>` tag, which you can use to validate whether the input is correct before allowing the form to be submitted. You can use the same `check()` function for this, with some changes.

I changed `onkeyup` to `oninput`, which more accurately detects #4 (user selects a suggested autofill option).

When the user presses ENTER, it attempts to submit the form, which is handled by the `onsubmit` handler in the `<form>` tag. This calls the `check()` function, which returns `true` if the input is valid, or `false` if it is invalid. If it returns `false`, this prevents the form from submitting.

```
<form onsubmit="return check()">
    <input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" oninput="check()" />

    <div class="text-end mt-3">
        <input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var count = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');
        count.value = count.value.replace(/\D/, '') // Remove non-digits
        if (
            0 == count.value.length // 0 chars entered
        ) {
            document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I sent only part of the code in the question, the complete code have a <form> tag. Your code doesn't comply with 1) as it allows non-numerals (although it doesn't show the button in this case). Additionally, the code doesn't match 2), I pressed ENTER, and it's going to the next question in the quiz. The problem is that if the user presses ENTER and skips the question, he will not be able to submit the form.

Comment: @aguyfrombrazil I have updated my code so it prevents non-digits from being entered. If you add the `onsubmit="return check()"` attribute to your `<form>` tag, it stops the form from being submitted.

Comment: The only problem is that if I don't fill anything in the input and press ENTER, it keeps jumping to the next question. This is question 2 of 5, if user press ENTER and reaches question 5, he will not be able to submit the form, however, instead of generating more work for the user by creating a button to go back to previous questions, I would like simply disabling ENTER without the button appearing. I thought about doing this with keyCode and an if, the ENTER code is 13. What would you change in your code to solve this?

Comment: @aguyfrombrazil I don't see how pressing ENTER could cause the form to submit when the input field is empty since it has a `required` attribute, which all modern browsers will honor. My JS also prevents the form from being submitted when the input field is empty (length == 0), so I still don't see how it could be happening. Perhaps your actual use case is significantly different from my example?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Check if the value is a number
function isNumber(str) {
  const regex = new RegExp('^(0|[1-9]\\d*)+$');
  return regex.test(str);
}
// Refresh the status of the submit button
function refreshSubmitBtn() {
  const val = $('input').val();
  const $btn = $('input[type="submit"]');
  if(isNumber(val)){
    $btn.removeClass('display-none');
  }else{
    $btn.addClass('display-none');
  }
}
// Add input listener
$('input').on('input', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  refreshSubmitBtn();
});
```

```css
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="display-none" />
</div>
```

Try this, it should help you.

If you want to wait for the user to input and then refresh, just adjust the condition of the input listener, like the following :

```
$('input').on('input', function(e)
```

Replace with

```
$('input').on('change', function(e)
```

I use jquery, but I see that you are using vanilla js in the question.

How to delete and add classes, if you want to use vanilla js to express, you can refer to the following code :

```
var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
element.classList.add('className');
element.classList.remove('className');
```

How to add a element listener, if you want to use vanilla js to express, you can refer to the following code :

```
var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
element .addEventListener('change', function(){
  //do something
});
```

Have a good day :)

Comment: I like your code. It's pretty easy to understand. I inserted the CSS class, and added the call to jQuery, but it didn't work. The button just doesn't appear, it doesn't give any error on the console. I'm new on this platform, how do I enter my code here without having to answer my own question?

Comment: You can re-edit your question, list the newly encountered problems below, or put the code in the comments in my answer